# Error running cassandra Word count example

Tags: cassandra

I am tryin to run the cassandra word count example on eclipse. I have loaded all the requisite jar files. But i am still getting some errors, in fileCassandraDemonThread.java

TNonblockingServer.Args serverArgs = new  TNonblockingServer.Args(serverTransport).inputTransportFactory(inTransportFactory)
                                                                                                     .outputTransportFactory(outTransportFactory)
                                                                                                     .inputProtocolFactory(tProtocolFactory)
                                                                                                     .outputProtocolFactory(tProtocolFactory)
                                                                                                     .processor(processor);
It throws the compilation error: TNonblockingServer.Args cannot be resolved to a type

Can somebody tell if i am missing any file to be linked?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have lib/*.jar on your runtime classpath, or less likely you have an old Thrift jar somewhere else that's getting used instead of the right one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess i had the old jar file. I downloaded the new thrift package and linked it to my project. It did not show the error after that.